# Boost wrapped python process dies when delete or freed array

Tags: python, boost, heap-memory, wrapper

I'm stuck in wrapping C dll with python.
dll side is provided blackbox and I made additional wrapper class.
python gives C dll numpy ndarray. then C dll process it and return it.

When I delete array in C, whole program dies. with or without deep copy. below are brief code to reproduce

python main

```
import mypyd, numpy

myobject = mypyd.myimpro()
image = readimg()    #ndarray
result = myobject.process(image) <- process die here with exit code -1073741819
```

dllmain header

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mypyd){
    class_<mywrapclass>("myimpro")
        .def("process", &mywrapclass::process)
}
```

c wrapper header

```
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

class mywrapclass{
    dllhandler m_handler;
    myimagestruct process(np::ndarray);
}
```

c wrapper code

```
mywrapclass::mywrapclass(){
    Py_Initialize();
    np::initialize();
    m_handler = initInDLL()
}

np::ndarray mywrapclass::process(np::ndarray input){
    myimagestruct image = ndarray2struct(input); ## deep copy data array
    myimagestruct result = processInDLL(m_handler, image);
    np::ndarray ret = struct2ndarray(result); ## also deep copy data array. just in case.
    return ret;
}
```

c header for dll(I can't modify this code. it's given with dll)

```
typedef struct {
    void *data
    ... size, type etc
} myimagestruct;

typedef void * dllhandler;

dllhandler = initInDLL();
myimagestruct processInDLL(myimagestruct);
```

sorry for wrong code. Initially, I naively thought boost.python or deep copying will solve this heap memory problem, lol. Tried almost every keyword in my brain but couldn't even find any point to start.

dll works perfect without boost wrapping. So it must be my part to resolve it.
Thanks for reading anyway.

Comment: did you initialize numpy?  `np::initialize();`

Comment: Anycorn Yes. just forgot to write it. Thanks.

Comment: you should post what the functions do and where segfault comes from.  or remove them if crash happens with them commented out